# Questions on Bluemix IOT Driver Behavior service

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, iot-driver-behavior

Came across the interesting service (Experimental) on Bluemix - Driver Behavior. Curious to know how it actually works, how does the data get to Bluemix from the car and is there a need to have an external app/device in the car to collect and post data to Bluemix something similar to Aviva's Rate my Drive app?

Answer (score 0):

One simple example is to use `IoT Platform` and `Node-RED` to receive car probe data via MQTT and send the received data into `Driver Behavior` service in the `Node-RED` workflow. You can have MQTT client in each driver's smart phone.

I am not familiar with the Aviva's Rate my Drive app, but as far as I searched, you might be able to develop similar kind of application which can analyze driving behavior from car probe data with the `Driver Behavior` service.